# Meaning of stack[-1][0] in Python

Tags: python, stack

I'm new to python and I'm trying to understand a piece of code but I don't understand what the s[-1][0] means.

```
s = [ ];
while(len(s)>0 and s[-1][0] <= el):
```

el is an int variable from and array.

Comment: `s[-1]` return last element from list(`s`).`s[-1][0]` means first element of the last item in `s`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Python supports negative indexing of iterables, e.g. lists. Let's assume that we have the following:

```py
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(x[-1][0])
```

**Output:**

```py
7
```

- `x[-1]` returns the last element of the list, i.e. the list `[7, 8, 9]`. Similarly, `x[-2]` returns the second to last element of the list, and so on.
- `x[-1][0]` returns the first element of the last list in `x`. In this case, the first element of `[7, 8, 9]` is `7`.